# Mount an FTP server locally

Tags: ftp, terminal, mount

I do a lot of work with files hosted on an FTP server. Currently to edit a file on the server I have to open the server in Cyberduck, navigate with the mouse to the folder I want and then click "Edit," which opens a temporary file. Anyway, editing files on the server would be way easier if I could use the terminal to navigate through the file directory and edit files. Is there a way to create a symbolic link in my home directory to an FTP server?

**edit:** I'm on a Mac

Comment: Your question is badly titled, it misleads people. What you want is a way to _mount_ an FTP server on your desktop (which is what W.Jackson's answer actually addresses). That's nothing to do with symbolic links ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your using linux you can mount an ftp site with curlftpfs. Check out this tutorial:  [Ubuntu Geeks Curlftpfs](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-mount-ftp-folder-to-local-directory-in-ubuntu.html)

If you are on windows you can use NetDrive:
[NetDrive.Net](http://netdrive.net/)

With either of these you can create links/shortcuts to your hearts content.

Comment: Mounted with Transmit.app on OS X:
ln: Operation not supported by device

Comment: @Mirko: What Kevin wants is not creating symbolic links on the FTP server, but rather access his remote files via a Terminal locally — which is a totally different thing. If you're interested in creating symbolic links on your FTP server, then this question is the one you should have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5589489/364446