# Accessing particular file in website

Tags: expressionengine

I've developed a push notification using php and put that one inside server, lets say in the folder `/system/expressionengine/controllers/cp/gcm_server_php/`.

But when I type its path:

```
www.website.com//system/expressionengine/controllers/cp/gcm_server_php/file.html
```

it shows that the website is not found. Can anyone please help on how to access that particular file. I'm newbie to this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you are trying to link to a file, which is not in your web root folder.

If so, you can create a symbolic link to the file in a folder accessible from the web.

For example (if /var/www is your web root)

```
ln -s /system/expressionengine/controllers/cp/gcm_server_php/ /var/www
```

creates a symbolic link to *gcm_server_php* in your web root, so *www.website.com/gcm_server_php/file.html* links to your file.

Comment: But this is for localhost. I have uploaded into remoter server. How can I create a symbolic link?

Comment: So you do not have SSH access to the server? If so, check whether your server allows custom commands, see [this queestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589489/create-symbolic-links-on-server-without-ssh-available)