# Laravel 5.8 - Uploaded images not showing on shared hosting

Tags: laravel

I've uploaded my Laravel site to shared hosting (I know....), the site has a image upload section which worked previously in my local set up.

The files do upload as expected but will not show in the view, I've looked everywhere for a solution so sorry if and answer is somewhere here already.

For example , this page http://www.navigatetheplanet.co.uk/blogs/England - the image at the top of the page was previously uploaded in local and is working as expected, but right at the bottom of the page there's a post with a image attached but return 404 ... from my investigations online it looks like it's something to do with the Symlink?

Comment: Have you created link to storage directory (`php artisan storage:link`)? Without access to ssh you can only ask your hosting provider to do it for you.

Comment: Could you precise how you load the images and how they are stored both in your dev file system and on the server side ?

Comment: @JulienRevaultd'A... thanks for responding! I'm loading them like this - <img src="/storage/{{$blogpost->photolink}}" width="100%" style="max-height: 237px;"> where $blogpost->photolink is a string which has the folders, filename and extension. The are stored within a folder in public/storage/blogimageupload.. this is replicated on my dev and production systems

Comment: @Harven I ran storage:link in dev, but as you rightly pointed out , I won't be able to ssh ... maybe I picked the wrong hosting service,

Comment: Here are some workarounds to create symlinks if you can't ssh https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589489/create-symbolic-links-on-server-without-ssh-available

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have ssh access then simply create a route.so you can hit this command simply by hitting url

```php
Route::get('/storage/link', function() {
    $command = 'storage:link';
    $result = Artisan::call($command);
    return Artisan::output();
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that , I've also just tried running it locally and the images aren't showing there either so looks like I must have some config issue?